# Doctrine: Symfony 2 foreign key null just before flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I am new to Symfony2 and Doctrine, i am stuck a little bit. Error receiving while saving to the database.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tho_provider (provid_name, provid_logo, provid_logo_path, created_time, provider_created_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["test", {}, "qwwwww", "2015-08-11 16:03:15", null]:
```

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'provider_created_by' cannot be null

I have the form where i am only getting provider name input and logo, rest is i am handling in the controller, Including provider_created_by which gets null just after the flush, before the flush command its showing the value.

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $entity = new Provider();
    $entity->setProvidLogoPath("qwwwww");
    $entity->setProviderCreatedBy($user);

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        //$entity->setCreatedBy($user);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('provider_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

I have entities, PROVIDER and USER. 
User's can create many provider and providers only belongs to one user. One to many relationship.

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
    /**
     * Provider
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="tho_provider")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProviderRepository")
     * @Vich\Uploadable
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     */
    class Provider
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="providers")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="provider_created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $users;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @ORM\Column(name="provid_name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $providName;

        /**
         * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
         *
         * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="general_image", fileNameProperty="provid_logo")
         *
         * @var File
         */
        private $imageFile;
        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="provid_logo", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $providLogo;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="provid_logo_path", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $providLogoPath;

        /**
         * @var \DateTime
         * @Assert\Type("\DateTime")
         * @ORM\Column(name="created_time", type="datetime")
         */
        private $createdTime;

        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="provider_created_by", type="integer")
         */
        public $providerCreatedBy;


        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set providName
         *
         * @param string $providName
         * @return Provider
         */
        public function setProvidName($providName)
        {
            $this->providName = $providName;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get providName
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getProvidName()
        {
            return $this->providName;
        }

        /**
         * Set providLogo
         *
         * @param string $providLogo
         * @return Provider
         */
        public function setProvidLogo($providLogo)
        {
            $this->providLogo = $providLogo;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get providLogo
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getProvidLogo()
        {
            return $this->providLogo;
        }

        /**
         * Set providLogoPath
         *
         * @param string $providLogoPath
         * @return Provider
         */
        public function setProvidLogoPath($providLogoPath)
        {
            $this->providLogoPath = $providLogoPath;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get providLogoPath
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getProvidLogoPath()
        {
            return $this->providLogoPath;
        }

        /**
         * Set createdTime
         *
         * @param \DateTime $createdTime
         * @return Provider
         */
        public function setCreatedTime($createdTime)
        {
            $this->createdTime = $createdTime;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get createdTime
         *
         * @return \DateTime 
         */
        public function getCreatedTime()
        {
            return $this->createdTime;
        }




        /**
         * Set users
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\User $users
         * @return Provider
         */
        public function setUsers(\AppBundle\Entity\User $users = null)
        {
            $this->users = $users;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get users
         *
         * @return \AppBundle\Entity\User 
         */
        public function getUsers()
        {
            return $this->users;
        }

        /**
         * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
         * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
         * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
         * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
         * during Doctrine hydration.
         *
         * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
         */
        public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
        {
            $this->imageFile = $image;

            if ($image) {
                // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
                // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
                $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return File
         */
        public function getImageFile()
        {
            return $this->imageFile;
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PrePersist
         */
        public function setCreatedTimeValue()
        {
            $this->createdTime = new \DateTime();
        }


        /**
         * Set providerCreatedBy
         *
         * @param integer $providerCreatedBy
         * @return Provider
         */
        public function setProviderCreatedBy($providerCreatedBy)
        {
            $this->providerCreatedBy = $providerCreatedBy;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get providerCreatedBy
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getProviderCreatedBy()
        {
            return $this->providerCreatedBy;
        }
    }
```

USER:

```
    <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    /**
     * User
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="tho_user")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields="email",message = "This email already exist.")
     * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username",message = "This username already taken")
     */
    class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
    {

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Provider", mappedBy="user")
         */
        protected $providers;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->providers = new ArrayCollection();
        }
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *@Assert\NotBlank(message="Username is required!")
         * @Assert\Length(min=3,minMessage="Minimum 3 characters long.")
         * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
         */
        protected $username;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $password;
        /**
         * @var array
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="roles",type="json_array")
         */
        private $roles = array();
        /**
         * @var bool
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="is_active",type="boolean")
         */
        private $isActive = true;

        /**
         * @var string
         *@Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\Email
         * @ORM\Column(name="email",type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $email;

        /**
         * @var string
         *@Assert\NotBlank()
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="first_name",type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $firstName;

        /**
         * @var string
         *@Assert\NotBlank()
         * @ORM\Column(name="last_name",type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $lastName;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="iata",type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $iata;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="job_title",type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $jobTitle;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="agency_phone",type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $agencyPhone;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="emergency_mobile",type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $emergencyMobile;

        /**
         * Storing password temporarily
         * @Assert\NotBlank()
         * @Assert\Length(min=6,minMessage="Minimum 6 characters long.")
         * @var string
         */
        private $plainPassword;
       /**
         * Get id
         *
        *
         * @return integer 
         */

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set username
         *
         * @param string $username
         * @return User
         */
        public function setUsername($username)
        {
            $this->username = $username;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get username
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getUsername()
        {
            return $this->username;
        }

        /**
         * Set password
         *
         * @param string $password
         * @return User
         */
        public function setPassword($password)
        {
            $this->password = $password;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get password
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        public function getRoles()
        {
            $roles = $this->roles;
            $roles[] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
            return array_unique($roles);
        }

        public function setRoles(array $roles)
        {
            $this->roles = $roles;
            return $this;
        }
        public function eraseCredentials()
        {
           $this->setPlainPassword(null);
        }

        public function getSalt()
        {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function isIsActive()
        {
            return $this->isActive;
        }

        /**
         * @param boolean $isActive
         */
        public function setIsActive($isActive)
        {
            $this->isActive = $isActive;
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether the user's account has expired.
         *
         * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
         * will throw an AccountExpiredException and prevent login.
         *
         * @return bool true if the user's account is non expired, false otherwise
         *
         * @see AccountExpiredException
         */
        public function isAccountNonExpired()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether the user is locked.
         *
         * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
         * will throw a LockedException and prevent login.
         *
         * @return bool true if the user is not locked, false otherwise
         *
         * @see LockedException
         */
        public function isAccountNonLocked()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether the user's credentials (password) has expired.
         *
         * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
         * will throw a CredentialsExpiredException and prevent login.
         *
         * @return bool true if the user's credentials are non expired, false otherwise
         *
         * @see CredentialsExpiredException
         */
        public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
        {
            return true;
        }

        /**
         * Checks whether the user is enabled.
         *
         * Internally, if this method returns false, the authentication system
         * will throw a DisabledException and prevent login.
         *
         * @return bool true if the user is enabled, false otherwise
         *
         * @see DisabledException
         */
        public function isEnabled()
        {
           return true;
        }



        /**
         * Get isActive
         *
         * @return boolean 
         */
        public function getIsActive()
        {
            return $this->isActive;
        }

        /**
         * Set email
         *
         * @param string $email
         * @return User
         */
        public function setEmail($email)
        {
            $this->email = $email;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get email
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }

        /**
         * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
         * String representation of object
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
         * @return string the string representation of the object or null
         */
        public function serialize()
        {
            return serialize(array(
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password
            ));
        }

        /**
         * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
         * Constructs the object
         * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
         * @param string $serialized <p>
         * The string representation of the object.
         * </p>
         * @return void
         */
        public function unserialize($serialized)
        {
            list(
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password
                ) = unserialize($serialized);
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getFirstName()
        {
            return $this->firstName;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $firstName
         */
        public function setFirstName($firstName)
        {
            $this->firstName = $firstName;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getLastName()
        {
            return $this->lastName;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $lastName
         */
        public function setLastName($lastName)
        {
            $this->lastName = $lastName;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getIata()
        {
            return $this->iata;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $iata
         */
        public function setIata($iata)
        {
            $this->iata = $iata;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getJobTitle()
        {
            return $this->jobTitle;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $jobTitle
         */
        public function setJobTitle($jobTitle)
        {
            $this->jobTitle = $jobTitle;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getAgencyPhone()
        {
            return $this->agencyPhone;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $agencyPhone
         */
        public function setAgencyPhone($agencyPhone)
        {
            $this->agencyPhone = $agencyPhone;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getEmergencyMobile()
        {
            return $this->emergencyMobile;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $emergencyMobile
         */
        public function setEmergencyMobile($emergencyMobile)
        {
            $this->emergencyMobile = $emergencyMobile;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPlainPassword()
        {
            return $this->plainPassword;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $plainPassword
         */
        public function setPlainPassword($plainPassword)
        {
            $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
        }



        /**
         * Set provider
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Provider $provider
         * @return User
         */
        public function setProvider(\AppBundle\Entity\Provider $provider = null)
        {
            $this->provider = $provider;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get provider
         *
         * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Provider 
         */
        public function getProvider()
        {
            return $this->provider;
        }

        /**
         * Add providers
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Provider $providers
         * @return User
         */
        public function addProvider(\AppBundle\Entity\Provider $providers)
        {
            $this->providers[] = $providers;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove providers
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Provider $providers
         */
        public function removeProvider(\AppBundle\Entity\Provider $providers)
        {
            $this->providers->removeElement($providers);
        }

        /**
         * Get providers
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
         */
        public function getProviders()
        {
            return $this->providers;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your metadata is

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="provider_created_by", type="integer")
 */
public $providerCreatedBy;
```

but you are passing an object (probably null):

```
$user = $this->getUser();
/* ... */
$entity->setProviderCreatedBy($user);
```

And the setter has no type hint:

```
public function setProviderCreatedBy($providerCreatedBy)
{
    $this->providerCreatedBy = $providerCreatedBy;

    return $this;
}
```

You must change your mapping of `$providerCreatedBy` to `ManyToOne` with `User` entity.

Comment: Thanks mate, i am checking for the user. Its logged in. things get working once i change the mapping :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your user has been logged in, `$this->getUser()` returns `null` if user is anonymous, also I think you should change your mapping info for `providerCreatedBy` field, from column type `integer` to `ManyToOne` relationship with `User` class..